# MySql select, get multiple occurances of a string

Tags: mysql, select, substring, locate

Column actions_serialized contains the following value:

> a:7:{s:4:"type";s:40:"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"any";s:10:"conditions";a:3:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_product";s:9:"attribute";s:3:"**sku**";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:17:"**SKU-ABC1**";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}i:1;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_product";s:9:"attribute";s:3:"**sku**";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:76:"**SKU-ABC203**";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}i:2;a:5:}}}

Now I need to fetch all SKUs in a separate line.

So I have the following query but it only returns the first instance of the SKU occurrence.

How do I get all other occurrences, and then how would I split them into a separate line?

Note, SKU occurrences may sometimes add up to 10+ SKUs.

```
select 
sr.id, 
 group_concat(distinct substring(sr.actions_serialized, 
 locate('sku', sr.actions_serialized)+47,
 locate(';s:18:"is_value_processed";b', sr.actions_serialized)-
 locate('sku', sr.actions_serialized)-48)) skus 

from from salesrule sr
group by sr.id
```

Above query returns only first instance of SKU. But desired results are:

```
id   skus
1    SKU-ABC1
1    SKU-ABC203
```

If not possible, then at least:

```
id   skus
1    SKU-ABC1,SKU-ABC203
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with CONCAT.

```
SELECT 
  sr.id, 
  CONCAT(distinct substring(sr.actions_serialized, 
  locate('sku', sr.actions_serialized)+47,
  locate(';s:18:"is_value_processed";b', sr.actions_serialized)-
  locate('sku', sr.actions_serialized)-48)) AS skus 
FROM salesrule sr
GROUP BY sr.id
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct substring(sr.actions_serialized,    locate('sku', sr.actions_serialized' at line 3